# using ffmpeg in linux, with vaapi, using filters, yuv420p colorspace is not correctly applied, green line, without hardware acceleration, no problem

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware

I try to convert gopro videos applying software filters using hwaccel capabilities.
Using only cpu, I used to encode color space with this option -pix-fmt  yuv420p, otherwise a black&white video is produced with a vertical green line.

Now, using ffmpeg to decode video using hardware acceleration vaapi (hwaccel_output_format), then download video (hwdownload) to CPU to apply software filters (-vf ....), then upload to GPU (hwupload) to apply hardware encoding (hevc_vaapi).

`ffmpeg   -hwaccel_output_format vaapi  -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f concat -safe 0 -i "./vids.txt"   -vf "hwdownload,format=yuv420p,eq=brightness=0.2:contrast=0.7:saturation=1:gamma=1,setpts=2*PTS,hwupload" -c:v hevc_vaapi  -rc_mode CQP -global_quality 21   video.mp4`

video is produced as black and white with a vertical green line. It appears that yuv420p is not applied at all. I have tried a lot of things, I failed to produce a properly video with these software filters. What i am doing wrong? Is there any other parameter that i must use? or vaapi dont support yuv420p color space at all?

sample unconverted video from wetransfer for 7 days: [here](https://%E2%80%8Bhttps://we.tl/t-o0nDKtFYSr)

(please add vaapi as tags)

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.3-1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
   built with gcc 12 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
   configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1 --toolchain=hardened
 --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-
 ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b
 --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d
 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-
 libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-
 libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg
 --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-
 librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine
 --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt
 --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame
 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp
 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
 --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal
 --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-
 libjxl --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-
 libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint
 --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e
 --enable-shared
   libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
   libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
   libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
   libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
   libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
   libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
   libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
   libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
```